# Signature/nullity function for a link obtained by parallel pushoffs of a knot?

Tags: gt.geometric-topology, knot-theory, 3-manifolds

Let $K$ be an oriented knot in $S^3$ together with a framing $n$.  Let $K(a,b)$ be the oriented link obtained by taking $a$ copies of the $n$-pushoff of $K$ with the same same orientation as $K$ and $b$ copies of the $n$-pushoff of $K$ with the opposite orientation as $K$.  In particular, $K(1,0) = K$ and $K(0,1)$ is the reverse of $K$.

What can be said about the signature function $\sigma_{K(a,b)}(\lambda)$ in terms of $\sigma_K(\lambda)$?

Edit: The answer is yes - in fact there is a nice formula for more general satellite constructions. In "Signatures of iterated torus knots" by Litherland, it is show that $\sigma_{K(a,b)}(\lambda) = \sigma_K(\lambda^{a-b})$ (See Theorem 2 and Remark 2 following it).

Can we say anything about the nullity $n_{K(a,b)}(\lambda)$ in terms of some info about $K$? In light of the above Edit, I should probably just ask about how the nullity function behaves under satellite operations.

Comment: There is an "obvious" Seifert surface for $K_n(a,b)$. Suppose $a>b$; then you can pair $b$ copies of oppositely oriented push-offs of $K$ with annuli (each of which twists $n$ times), and add a copy of the Seifert surface for the $(a-b,(a-b)n)$-cable of $K$, $J$. (Then you probably need to add tubes to make it connected.) But the signature should be related to that of $J$ and that of $b$ negative $n$-Hopf links.

Comment: I might be wrong, but I suspect you are trying to apply Gilmer's surgery formula for Casson-Gordon invariants. If this is the case, you might want to take a look at Theorem 6.7 of this paper: http://www.unige.ch/math/folks/cimasoni/signature.pdf . It gives a surgery formula which uses the multivariable signature instead of Levine-Tristram signatures of cables.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As Marco mentions, it appears you are studying cables. These are particular examples of satellite operations. As you already noticed, Litherland proves that if $S$ is a winding number $n$ satellite with pattern $P$ and companion $C$, then
$$ \sigma_S(\omega)=\sigma_P(\omega)+\sigma_C(\omega^n). $$ 
For the nullity, I think the formula is similar:
$$ \eta_S(\omega)=\eta_P(\omega)+\eta_C(\omega^n). $$ 
I think a proof can be found in here in a more general setting, namely "splicing":
https://arxiv.org/pdf/1802.01836.pdf (Theorem 5.2).
The way to recover satellites from splices is for instance explained here:
https://arxiv.org/pdf/1409.5873.pdf (Section 2.4).

For the nullity, you can also prove this "by hand". I think that the most painless way is to view $\eta_K(\omega)$ as the dimension of a twisted homology vector space: $ \eta_K(\omega)=\operatorname{dim}_{\mathbb{C}} H_1(S^3 \setminus K;\mathbb{C}^\omega)$. You can then run a Mayer-Vietoris argument for the satellite knot exterior and the result will follow.

Comment: Thanks that is perfect and I found your review article very helpful :-)